# How to check if the new document is being added in a Firestore collection

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore to store the data in my application and nodeJs as my client sdk.

Give below is the Firestore structure.

[image]

Documents in `CollectionA1` is updated by endpoint `endpoint_A1`, and documents in `CollectionA2` is updated by `endpoint_A2`.

Whenever I get request in one of the endpoint I need to check if there is any new document is being written to the other collection.

For example, lets say I get request in `endpoint_A1` and this adds the document in `CollectionA1`. After this I need to check if there is new document is currently being written in `CollectionA2` then proceed.

It would be really helpful if you could give some insights on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore is by default offline first. That means all data you write is written to the cache and synced "later" to the backend. This can make it look like that it takes longer to sync the data. You can also use the firestore code on the client side as it where synchronous because you don't need to wait on it to finish.

Usualy the realtime listeners notice such writes to the cache and inform you as if they where written to the backend.

To check if yout `doc` is added to the collection on the server you would need to setup your realtime listeners to include `includeMetadataChanges` like here:

```js
db.collection("cities").doc("SF")
    .onSnapshot({
        // Listen for document metadata changes
        includeMetadataChanges: true
    }, (doc) => {
        // ...
    });
```

You can red more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-metadata-changes).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems to be the solution I was looking for. 
I will check if this works in my application and update you.